# Exporting MySQL database with FTS index

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

I was recently doing migration of a MySQL database and found an issue with regards to FTS indexing.

Here are the steps that produced the issue:

I exported the database with the following command:

```
mysqldump -p -u username database_name > export.sql
```

and imported it with:

```
mysql -p -u username database_name < export.sql
```

Following which, I ran the FTS indexing command on each of the tables that needed them:

`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT(colnames...)`

When checking the table status for these tables, the number of records were correct. However, the `index_length` was very different from the original database (the one we exported from).

The result was that FTS worked partially (some strings matched but not all). So if I did a `MATCH` with a string like "test", it would work on both but when I did a `MATCH`with a string like "hello", it would only work on the original database.

What could be the cause of this behaviour? I was very careful to ensure that all the tables were added to the FTS index. The tables have around 150,000 records each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always like this isn't it. Spending hours trying to solve a problem and within minutes of posting on StackOverflow, the answer comes to you.

So the issue was with the parameters for FTS in the sql config file. Previously, I had removed the stopwords list and also reduced the minimum word length. Forgot to bring these parameters over to the new server.